# Do vouchers offered by EU airlines for Coronavirus cancellations turn into a full refund if not used?

Tags: airlines, eu, covid-19

My family's flights with AlItalia later this month have of course been affected by Coronavirus. We cannot get refunds, only vouchers are offered, as with basically all airlines at the moment. We booked through an agent, Supersaver.

Now *in the Netherlands*, apparently government decided to allow these vouchers only with a few conditions, see [this page](https://www.eccnederland.nl/en/news/coronavirus-and-flight-voucher-what-you-need-know). It includes the condition:

> Flight voucher not used? Ask for refund!
>
> If you have accepted the flight voucher and you are not able to use it, you are entitled to a full > refund of the ticket price. The airline takes the initiative to repay

Has Italy also published rules for airline vouchers that include a statement on this?

Has the EU?

Comment: related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156691/do-vouchers-offered-by-eu-airlines-for-coronavirus-cancellations-include-taxes-a

Comment: There is no coherent decision on EU261 suspension right now, individual countries and aviation authorities are choosing how to handle this on their own based on airlines being unable to handle such significant events with regard to refunds and EU261 compensation.

Comment: Isn't the answer on the page? “The Dutch Ministry of Infrastructure allows this initiative despite it being contrary to European rules.” Note that this is legally highly questionable but in practice that might not make a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do vouchers offered by EU airlines for Coronavirus cancellations include taxes and fees?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156691/do-vouchers-offered-by-eu-airlines-for-coronavirus-cancellations-include-taxes-a)

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith: I split it into two questions because I thought I was going to get commentary that I shouldn't put multiple questions in one, now I get the other comment :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "affected"? Do you mean cancelled?

Comment: @Lag: moved to a different time anyway, not sure if the original flight was cancelled. But we are not allowed to travel anyway.

Comment: That would depend if the airline is still in business when this is over.

Comment: @gerrit: improved the question a bit. I would like to know if the Italian government has published something about these vouchers, that maybe says something similar as the Dutch government's.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That makes a big difference, that's one of the points I was trying to make in my comment on the other question. If the flight wasn't cancelled (or was moved following the rules defined in EU261), your being unable to travel is not the airline's problem and they owe you nothing, not even this voucher the Dutch authorities illegally created. Writing “affected” to dance around the issue carries little weight and just obscures your situation.

Comment: In other words: a voucher the airline is offering as a commercial gesture for a flight that hasn't been cancelled would not be covered by any special rules for cancelled flights, not even the Dutch one.

Answer (score 1):

If your flight has been cancelled, EU law gives you the right to choose between a refund, the earliest flight available or a flight at a date of your choice ([article 8 of Regulation (EC) No 261/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32004R0261:en:HTML)). [See this EU help page](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#reimbursement-cancellation-1).

At the time of writing this answer, the [Alltalia English language help page about the situation](https://www.alitalia.com/en_en/fly-alitalia/news-and-activities/news/info-flights.html) states that you have that choice if your flight has been cancelled:

> Passengers who have had their flight canceled
>
> All passengers in possession of an Alitalia (055) ticket whose flight has been canceled can request the following by 31 August:
>
> - To change your booking for another trip taking place by 31 March or within the period of validity of the ticket
> - A voucher, valid for one year, to fly to any destination serviced by Alitalia.
> - A refund of the price of the ticket or of the remaining value of the part of the trip which has not yet been completed

That page also says:

> Passengers who no longer wish to fly as per the schedule indicated on
>   their ticket
>
> All passengers who purchased a ticket issued by 30 April for a flight
>   departing from 23 February to 30 June can request the following by 31
>   August:
>
> - To change your booking for another trip taking place by 31 March 2021 or within the period of validity of the ticket
> - A refund with a voucher of equal value to the ticket purchased, valid for one year, to fly to any destination offered by Alitalia.

If your flight hasn't been cancelled you can accept the airline's offer, try to negotiate or wait until the flight is cancelled when you are legally entitleed to a refund.

Some customers are demanding refunds before flights are officially cancelled. But airlines aren't legally obliged. Right now, airlines are trying to appear very flexible. But they won't cancel flights and issue refunds unless they think it's in their best interests or they are compelled (in which case they will demand subsidies from the national government or EU).

Comment: This wouldn't really apply since he booked via agent.